# Pentaho Kettle is not working for Vertica DB

Tags: pentaho, kettle, vertica

I need to parse a CSV file and write the data to a Vertica database. The issue is that I get an error when I create a Vertica database connection in Spoon. The following is the error at the end of the post.

I tried copying the following two JAR files and adding them to `libext/jdbc`:

> vertica-jdbc-4.1.14.jar and vertica-jdk5-6.1.2-0.jar

But the above didn't help. I am looking for pointers!

**Error**:

```
Error connecting to database [Vertica Dev] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
com.vertica.jdbc.Driver

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:366)
```

Comment: Which one do you use to connect outside of Pentaho? Try using only that one. You may need to restart Pentaho.

Comment: Which version of PDI?

Answer (score 6):

The two JAR files you copied are of two different versions of Vertica and do not use the same class.

vertica-jdk5-6.1.2-0.jar will expose  `com.vertica.jdbc.Driver` whereas version 4 will expose `com.vertica.Driver`.

The error message thus makes obvious that Pentaho is looking for `com.vertica.jdbc.Driver` (version 5, thus). If it fails, it probably is because the JAR version 4 is loaded first.

Try to delete the version 4 only from the libext/jdbc, keep the version 5, and restart Pentaho.

On a side note, this class is hardcoded in Pentaho, so if you do need to use the JAR version 4 and feel adventurous, you just need to get the Pentaho source, update VerticaDatabaseMeta.java, and recompile.